# Laravel: SelectRange with Step size

Tags: php, laravel

I would like to create a field in Laravel with a select range attribute

```
 {{ Form::selectRange('number', 1, 1500000) }}
```

I would like the range to be between 1 and 1500000 with an increment step size of 50000

Currently when I create this, it just creates a super long select field with increments of 1

Answer (score 3):

I created a Form macro for this, basically extending the existing selectRange macro:

```
class FormBuilder extends FB
{
    public function selectRangeWithInterval($name, $start, $end, $interval, $default = null, $attributes = [])
    {
        if ($interval == 0) {
            return $this->selectRange($name, $start, $end, $default, $attributes);
        }
        $items = [];
        $startValue = $start;
        $endValue = $end;
        if ($interval < 0) {
            $interval *= -1;
        }
        if ($start > $end) {
            if ($interval > 0) {
                $interval *= -1;
            }
            $startValue = $end;
            $endValue = $start;
        }
        for ($i=$startValue; $i<$endValue; $i+=$interval) {
            $items[$i . ""] = $i;
        }
        $items[$endValue] = $endValue;
        if (!in_array($default, $items)) {
            $items[$default] = $default;
        }

        return $this->select($name, $items, $default, $attributes);
    }
}
```

This can then be used in your view something like this:

```
{{ Form::selectRangeWithInterval('weightOfSackOfFeathers', 0, 7500, 150, null, ['class' => 'form-control input-xs']) }}
```

Answer (score 1):

I did it using straight php, because AFAIK laravel doesnt support steps with selectrange so far.

```
<select name="min_price" class="form-control">
<?php for ($i = 1; $i <= 15; $i++) : ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $i*10000; ?>"><?php echo number_format($i*10000); ?></option>
<?php endfor; ?>


    e(Input::get('min_price'))</select>
```