# Laravel selectRange blank option

Tags: forms, laravel, laravel-4, formbuilder

I am creating a "day" select dropdown. With a selectRange I can do this:

```
{{ Form::selectRange('day', 1, 31, $day) }}
```

The problem is, when the form loads, if `$day` is not set it selects `1` by default. Is it possible to use selectRange to give them a "Please Choose" option that has a NULL value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe there is a way of achieving this with the built in selectRange, however it is possible using [form macros](http://laravel.com/docs/html#custom-macros). The following macro performs roughly what you're looking for, though may require some cleanup.

```
Form::macro('selectRangeWithDefault', function($name, $start, $end, $selected = null, $default = null, $attributes = [])
{
    if ($default === null) {
        return Form::selectRange($name, $start, $end, $selected, $attributes);
    }
    $items = [];
    if (!in_array($default, $items)) {
        $items['NULL'] = $default;
    }

    if($start > $end) {
        $interval = -1;
        $startValue = $end;
        $endValue = $start;
    }  else {
        $interval = 1;
        $startValue = $start;
        $endValue = $end;
    }

    for ($i=$startValue; $i<$endValue; $i+=$interval) {
        $items[$i . ""] = $i;
    }

    $items[$endValue] = $endValue;

    return Form::select($name, $items, isset($selected) ? $selected : $default, $attributes);
});
```

Usage is as follows:

```
{{ Form::selectRangeWithDefault('day', 1, 31, $day, 'Please Choose...') }}
```

Note that I got the idea and the basis for my code from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25069699/3492098

Answer (score 7):

Use Form::select instead.

```
{{ Form::select('day', array('' => 'Please Choose...') + range(1,31)) }}
```

Answer (score 6):

Use Form Select with range and array_combine if you want to modify the option value:

```
{{ Form::select('month', array('all' => 'all') + array_combine(range(1,12),range(1,12)) ) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

this one works with reverse list :

```
Form::macro('selectRangeWithDefault', function($name, $begin, $end, $selected = null, $default = null, $attributes = [])
{
    if (!is_array($default) || $default === null) {
        return Form::selectRange($name, $begin, $end, $selected, $attributes);
    }
    $range = $default + array_combine($range = range($begin, $end), $range);

    return Form::select($name, $range, $selected, $attributes);
});
```

Exemple :

```
{!! Form::selectRangeWithDefault('year', date('Y'), 1915, $user->getBirthYear(), ['' => 'YYYY']) !!}
```

And if you are looking how to add a macro : [Where to put HTML macros in laravel 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28345051/where-to-put-html-macros-in-laravel-5)

Answer (score 0):

Use **Form::select** instead of **Form::selectRange**

Also, according to the best practices you can use the placeholder parameter in order to create a blank option.

```
{{ Form::select('day', range(1, 31), null, ['placeholder' => '']) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

**use placeholder**

```
 {{ Form::selectRange('day', 1, 31, $day,['class' => 'form-control input-lg','id'=>'day','placeholder' => 'Please Choose']) }}
```