# Where to put HTML macros in laravel 5?

Tags: macros, laravel-5

In laravel 4 I used to have HTML macros which were used in multiple views, like:

```
HTML::macro('minipics', function($pic)
{
    //
}
```

For that I had a `macros.php` file in the `/app` folder. I could not find out where to put the macros in laravel 5. Should I use the 'macroable' feature for that?

### edit:

I ended up using `@include()`, giving it the needed values.

```
@include('shared.minipics', $mpics = $ppics)
@include('shared.minipics', $mpics = $randpics)
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I've moved my macros into a "resources/macros/..." directory because I think they belong with all of the other view related code. To load them I'm using a service provider which looks something like this:

```
<?php namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class MacroServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    /**
     * Bootstrap the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        require base_path() . '/resources/macros/macro1.php';
        require base_path() . '/resources/macros/macro2.php';
        // etc...
    }

    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }

}
```

Comment: to add to this, if you use the following in the boot method: 
`foreach(glob(base_path('resources/macros/*.macro.php')) as $filename){  require_once($filename); }`
you can autload all <file>.macro.php files in eliminating the need to update the provider

Answer (score 0):

You can do it the same way as in Laravel 4.

Place your `macros.php` file in the `/app` folder.

Then in your `composer.json` you do this

```
"autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        },
        "files": [
            "app/macros.php"  <-- Put this here
        ]
    },
```

Comment: I tried to add a `use Html;` in the macros file, but still get "PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Html' not found in /srv/.....macros.php on line 4". Do I have to load the class somehow?

Comment: Yes - it is listed in the Upgrade guide here - http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/upgrade#upgrade-5.0  - scroll down to "Form & HTML Helpers"

Comment: I already had the "Form & HTML Helpers" installed previously like in the link. That already worked. Only since I added "app/macros.php" to composer.json, when I run `composer update` I get a white screen and the cli output "PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Html' not found in /srv/http/site5/app/macros.php on line 3". That's why I thought, that possibly some `namespace` or `use` could be missing in macros.php. The class is the same (`Html`) with lowercase letters in the aliases array and in macros.php. The app is named and the name is also present in composer.json (psr-4).

Comment: Try `\Html::macro('...`?

Comment: Changed to `\Html::macro('..` and moved 1 line below to see if it is 'read', but: `php artisan optimize PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Html' not found in /srv/http/site5/app/macros.php on line 4` :( `composer dump-autoload` does not throw an error, but `composer update` the same error as the artisan command

Comment: The HTML class is not loaded at this point in your app cycle, create a service provider and require it there.